# Submit button not clicking selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I came across java code of automating a website and I changed to python and executed.

While executing the code submit button is not working. can anyone suggest a better way to implement this code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://in.musafir.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
departure = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='From']"))).send_keys("Kochi")

arrival = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='To']"))).send_keys("Mumbai")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='StartDate']").send_keys("21/08/19")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='EndDate']").send_keys("27/08/19")
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='AdultsFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(2)

s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ChildrenFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='optional submit button yellow flightsOnly_all buttonBound customButton']").click()
```

Comment: Can you try using a relative xpath for example `.//a[contains(@class,'submit button')]`

Comment: @work_ishaan tried but not working.

Comment: The issue seems to be that your code isn't able to locate the element properly

Answer (score 0):

Can you try xpath with display name of the button like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Submit')]").click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Submit')]"}

Comment: need to use the exact name displaying on the button, in your case its "Find flights", so your xpath will be  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[contains(text(),'Find flights')]").click()

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click the button because your script fails to properly fill the departure and destination cities.

After typing you need to click at one of auto-suggestion results appearing in the box below the input:

[image]

So you need to add another [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until the auto suggestion list items is visible and then choose the desired city from the list. The relevant [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) would be something like:

```
//li[@class='airport active']/em
```

Full code just in case:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://in.musafir.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
departure = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='From']"))).send_keys("Kochi")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='airport active']/em"))).click()

arrival = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='To']"))).send_keys("Mumbai")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='airport active']/em"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='StartDate']").send_keys("21/08/19")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='EndDate']").send_keys("27/08/19")
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='AdultsFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(2)

s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ChildrenFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//a[@class='optional submit button yellow flightsOnly_all buttonBound customButton']").click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but, we need to add the same for the arrival and departure date.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution, Below is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://in.musafir.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
departure = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='From']"))).send_keys("Kochi")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='airport active']/em"))).click()

arrival = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='To']"))).send_keys("Mumbai")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='airport active']/em"))).click()

d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='StartDate']"))).click()
d2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@date='2019-08-29']"))).click()

d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='EndDate']"))).click()
d2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@date='2019-08-30']"))).click()

s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='AdultsFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(2)

s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ChildrenFlight']"))
s1.select_by_index(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//a[@class='optional submit button yellow flightsOnly_all buttonBound customButton']").click()

# driver.quit()
```